# Assembly get input string

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am trying to get the input string from keyboard and redisplay it abut I dont know why I am getting a message twice. For example:
Enter your string:1234567
The output will be

Your input:1234567
Your input:

And I wonder why I am getting it twice. Here is my code:

```
data segment
prompt  db  0dh,0ah,"Enter your string(7 Chars Max): $"
nam     db  8 dup(?) ; 7 plus term char $
msg1    db  0dh,0ah,"Your input: $"
sev db 7 dup(?)
data ends
code segment
assume cs:code,ds:data
START:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov dx,offset prompt
mov ah,09h
int 21h
lea si,nam
mov cx,7
et:mov ah,01
int 21h
mov [si],al
inc si
loop et
mov si+sev,'$'
mov dx,offset msg1
mov ah,09h
int 21h
lea dx,nam
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
Code ends
end Start
```

Comment: `mov si+sev, '$'` most likely doesn't do what you want it to do. Why not just `mov [si], '$'`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen is right, after the loop `[si]` is already pointing to the end of the string, so `+sev` is unnecessary.

Comment: Also `sev` is not equal to 7, it is another 7 byte memory block so adding its offset to `si` points to somewhere very wrong

Comment: Yes, this was the reason, now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume with the line `mov si+sev, '$'` you are trying to add the end marker to the string. This is not correct since `sev` is another memory block of seven bytes so adding its offset to `si` will point to somewhere completely different and may even cause problems.

Since you're reading values and incrementing `si` each time you can just use `mov [si], '$'` to write the end marker after the last character read.